# How to mock arbitrary blocks of code in Mockito Scala?

Tags: scala, mockito

So I have the following bit of code

```
class MetricsLogger {

  def measure[T](name:String)(operation: => T): T = {
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val result = try {
        operation
       } finally {
        logMetric(Metric(name, System.currentTimeMillis - startTime, StandardUnit.Milliseconds))
      }
      result
  }
}
```

Where log Metric is some kind of side effect (e.g. upload metric to cloudwatch).

Now I am doing this like

```
def measuredOp = measure("metricName") { someOperation }
```

Here some operation is making some network calls.

Now I have to stub measured op.

So my stub is as the follows:-

```
val loggingMetrics = mock[MetricsLogger] // mock is from MockitoSugar trait
```

and my stubbing is like

```
 Mockito.when(loggingMetrics.measure(Matchers.anyString())(Matchers.anyObject())).thenReturn(???)
```

So obviously my stubbing is wrong, but I cannot figure how to stub this properly.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with Mockito - the combination of by-name argument and multiple argument lists makes this especially tricky. Might be possible to do with ScalaMock - see discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specs2-users/dd_LXkQMJvo

Comment: override this method instead of mocking during test object creation.

Comment: This looks fine to me... what is the issue here? The `.thenReturn` block just needs to return the correct return type (in this case maybe an object?). I personally prefer using `ArgumentMatchers` instead of `Matchers` but that's just my preference. What do you think is wrong with your stubbing?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley - Its incomplete for starters. Also I cant reconcile : => T and ret T.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito doesn't support that as by-name parameters it's a concept that doesn't exists in Java, however, [mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala) does support this from version 0.4.0 (try 0.4.0 or 0.4.2, ignore 0.4.1)

I just run a quick test like this

```
import org.mockito.{ MockitoSugar, ArgumentMatchersSugar }

class StackOverflowTest extends WordSpec with MockitoSugar with scalatest.Matchers with ArgumentMatchersSugar {

  "mock[T]" should {

    "it should work with by-name params" in {
      val loggingMetrics = mock[MetricsLogger]

      when(loggingMetrics.measure(any)(any)).thenReturn("it worked!")

      loggingMetrics.measure("test")("") shouldBe "it worked!"
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of that library although it's part of the official Mockito suite